# How do I read JSON on my Golang server that I've posted from iOS using NSData?

Tags: ios, json, swift, go, nsdata

I'm trying to validate a receipt by sending it to my custom server from iOS.

I have my `NSMutableURLRequest` and set it up as so:

```
    let body: [String: AnyObject] = ["receipt": receipt, "prod_id": productID]

    let optionalJson: NSData?

    do {
        optionalJson = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(body, options: [])
    } catch _ {
        optionalJson = nil
    }

    guard let json = optionalJson else { return }

    request.HTTPBody = json
```

Then I send it off to my server which is written in Go, but I don't know how to then read the data.

Previously I sent only the data (in raw form, not a JSON structure), and then turned into a base 64 encoded string as so before shipping it off:

```
data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
encodedString := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(data)
```

But now I the JSON structure that links a `prod_id` with is a `string`, as well as the receipt data, which I assume is `bytes`. How do I extract that into readable JSON then turn it into a base 64 encoded string as above?

I guess I'm not sure what structure the JSON would take.

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like :

```
type Foo strut {
  Bar string `json:"bar"`
}

// extract
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
if err != nil {
  return err
}
defer request.Body.Close()

v := &Foo{}
json.Unmarshal(data, v)
```

The `json:"bar"` in `Foo` binds the JSON struct with the Go struct

Answer (score 0):

You should create struct like below:

```
type MyRequest struct {
    Receipt string `json:"receipt"`
    ProdID string `json:"prod_id"`
}
```

then decode request body:

```
func handleMyRequest(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
    var myReq MyRequest
    err := decoder.Decode(&myReq)
    if err != nil {
        panic()
    }
    log.Println(myReq)
}
```